# I don't see my local backups in Azure Backup center

Tags: backup, azure, azure-backup

I'm evaluating Azure backup for on premise computers.

### Scenario

My scenario is simple :

- I want to backup the computer of my 50 users to the cloud.
- I want to backup 1 or 2 folders on each computer
- Each user should be able to restore his own computer but should not have access to other computers. He should not even see the list of backed up computers.
- My team should have access to all backup so we can restore any computer

### What I did

This said, I created a Recovery Service Vault. Using MARS, I defined the backup for the 2 computers.
I can then restore the backup if needed.
Great!

### What I need

I want to manage all my backups in one place, and I thought that Azure Backup Center was that place.
Unfortunately, my local backups are not considered in the Backup Center. I can see here only the backup for Azure resources (Azure VM, Azure Disks, ...) which are not what I backed up.

More importantly, I need to be alerted when a computer didn't send his backup to Azure in the last 24 hours (computer off, no internet, ...).

I just can't find the right place to manage and check my backups.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Contact Azure support.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Backup Center only supports resources running in Azure.

You can use Recovery Services for managing and monitoring your backups in one place.
Some information about how you could use this is available in the documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-monitoring-built-in-monitor
This also states on how to be alerted about your backup jobs.